# Why is the use of indoor plumbing allowed on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory, melacha-creative-work, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Use of indoor plumbing on shabbos involves moving water or waste from/to public and private domains, which could involve a biblical prohibition of hotzoa. Why is this allowed on shabbos?